Create index for own custom data in elasticpress from wordpress plugin
I creating a plugin , I inserted some custom data into database mysql , I need to create an index for that custom data in elastic press for my future search. I am confused about creating an index for own custom data. Can anyone suggest ep function name for index creation and insert data into that index or refer some blog or documention.

You should ask ElasticPress for the solution to this or check their documentation.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
